# PHP Date adds 25 hours but should add 24 hours

Tags: php, date, time

PHP is calculating my date wrong!

```
echo "Calc: ";
echo date("d.m.Y G:i", $date);
echo "(" . $date . ")";
echo "+";
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 86400);
echo "(86400)";
echo "=";

$date = $date + 86400;  

echo date("d.m.Y G:i", $date);
echo "(" . $date . ")";
```

Displays:

```
Calc: 25.03.2017 11:02 (1490436120) +00:00:00 (86400) = 26.03.2017 12:02 (1490522520)
```

But why does PHP do this? And it does it only in the night from Saturday to Sunday!

Comment: We change time this sunday :)

Comment: 26.03.2017 is the day when DST starts in Europe this year.

Comment: Every year the same question :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no bug here, as this weekend we are switching to DST

Comment: @bub well that comment is the answer so posting it as an answer is the right thing to do